# Two code blocks of optional computed properties, why can't I use .first in this way?

Tags: ios, swift

```
private var oneAndOnly {
   get {
     let faceCardIndices = cards.indices.filter({cards[$0].isFaceUp})
     return faceCardIndices.count == 1 ? faceCardIndices.first : nil
   }
}
```

vs

```
private var oneAndOnly {
   get {
     return cards.indices.filter({cards[$0].isFaceUp}).first
   }
}
```

If `.first` returns nil anyway when there is no element, I would assume that these are equivalent but they are not. The first block actually gives me a new index where as the second block gets stuck.

Comment: Can you provide a full example someone could paste into a playground that reproduces your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'stuck'? As a sidenote, there is a variant of `first` which includes a filter as well [`first(where:...`]

Comment: Don't you need to specify the type. ex: `private var oneAndOnly:String? {`

Comment: @Alladinian On a side note, there is also `cards.index(where: { $0.isFaceUp })` :) But that's equivalent first the second one, not the first one.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!!

Comment: Had you said `return faceCardIndices.count >= 1 ? faceCardIndices.first : nil` then the results would be the same.  But, that is more simply written as just `return faceCardIndices.first`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that the first block will find the index of the flipped card only if there is exactly one such card.

The second block will return the index of the first card that is flipped, even if there are multiple such cards.

In other words for:

```
faceCardIndices = [5]
```

both methods will return `5` but for:

```
faceCardIndices = [1, 5]
```

the first will return `nil` while the second will return `1`.

In all other aspects the methods are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
return faceCardIndices.count == 1 ? faceCardIndices.first : nil
```

if `faceCardIndices.count` is **NOT** equal to `1`, then `faceCardIndices.first` does not even get evaluated... it simply returns `nil`.

With your other code:

```
return cards.indices.filter({cards[$0].isFaceUp}).first
```

it will try to get `.first`, regardless of the result of `.filter` ... and that can lead to trying to get the *first element of zero elements*.

Comment: When the number of elements is zero, `.first` should return `nil`. The difference is that the first block returns `nil` even when there are **more** than one cards up.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be equivalent functions when `cards` is an empty array, with both functions returning `nil`.

In playgrounds:

```
struct Card {
    var isFaceUp: Bool
}


struct Test {
    var cards = [Card]()

    var oneAndOnly: Int? {
        get {
            let faceCardIndices = cards.indices.filter({cards[$0].isFaceUp})
            return faceCardIndices.count == 1 ? faceCardIndices.first : nil
        }
    }

    var oneAndOnly2: Int? {
        get {
            return cards.indices.filter({cards[$0].isFaceUp}).first
        }
    }
}

var test = Test()
test.oneAndOnly     //nil
test.oneAndOnly2    //nil
```

Also, when `cards` contains 4 cards, with one face up, both functions return the same index of `2`.

```
var test = Test()
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: false))
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: false))
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: true))
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: false))
test.oneAndOnly     //2
test.oneAndOnly2    //2
```

The difference comes into play when the array contains more than 1 face up card, with the first function returning `nil` and the second function returning the index of the first face up card. This is due to the `faceCardIndices.count == 1` constraint that is only used in the first function.

```
var test = Test()
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: false))
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: true))
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: true))
test.cards.append(Card(isFaceUp: false))
test.oneAndOnly     //nil
test.oneAndOnly2    //1
```